# Android-RoundCorner for a imageView

Tags: android

I am new to android.I what to know how to apply round corner to imageview.

I have applied border for the imageview but it does not draw round corner for the image.
If any one knows Please help me.Thanks in advance......

[image]

Comment: While creating the image itself try to create rounded corner images.

Comment: but if images are retrieved from the internet?